# get DataView from DataTable based on search condition - C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telerik, silverlight-5.0, telerik-grid

```
Telerik.Data.DataTable DataTable dt = (DataTable)SessionApp.SessionManager.Session["mySessionDataTable"];
```

I the above telerik dataTable but i would wish to extract a Dataview out of dt based on a filter condition.

With an ADO.NET DataTable i would have used some code like

```
// find the record for Tom
DataView view = new DataView(dt.Tables[0]);
view.RowFilter = "Name = 'Tom'";
```

to my disappointment i can't find some thing like that with the Telerik DataTable.

Comment: Does it filter your view?

Comment: If not try to use linq.